# Model selection between parametric nonparametric methods

Tags: model-selection, aic, likelihood

I have a real data set ($n=50$).  I would like to fit some parametric models to this data set and then compare the maximum log-likelihood values with my spline model which is a nonparametric model.  Could I use AIC criteria as a model selection?  If not, which model selection criteria can I use?

Comment: It is likely that N=50 translates to an inability to estimate even the overall intercept with zero predictors.  Concentrate first on the sample size required to do what you want.  N=70 is required to estimate residual standard deviation well.  N=96 is required to estimate just the intercept in a binary Y model.  AIC has a low probability of finding the best model with small N.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generally use AIC to choose between parametric and nonparametric models. Parametric and nonparametric models have different modeling assumptions. The traditional AIC is based on a function of the likelihood. Likelihoods of parametric and nonparametric models are not always comparable.

An alternative that in theory can naturally compare parametric and nonparametric is a generalized degrees of freedom based criteria. See Ye's [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2669609) or Huang and Chen's paper for geostatistical data

Comment: You can't *generally* use AIC to compare parametric and non-parametric models. But for many spline models, it is a fairly reasonable thing to do (assuming it's not a penalized spline).

Comment: Yes, but in practice most spline based models are penalized to control overfitting.                                                                                                         Also, AIC may be used to choose the appropriate spline based model to use, but that's a different problem of the one stated by shany

Comment: If AIC can discriminate between different smoothing parameters, why can't it discriminate between a smoothing parameter of infinity and a smoothing parameter of 0?  I guess this assumes an unpenalized intercept.